# Convert code from previous TensorFlow version to new TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

How can I convert this code to the newest TensorFlow version 2.0?

```
def create_placeholders(n_x,n_y):

    X=t.placeholder(tf.float32,[n_x,None],name='X')
    Y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[n_y,None],name='Y')
    
    return X,Y
```

Comment: if you think the answer was helpful, kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for placeholders anymore. Yon can simply assume that you have a tensor variable

```
def create_placeholders(n_x,n_y):

   X=tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32,initial_value=[n_x,None],name='X',dtype=tf.flot32)
   Y=tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32,initial_value=[n_y,None],name='Y',dtype=tf.flot32)

   return X,Y
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

However, when I call the function, 
X,Y=create_placeholders(12288,6) 

I am getting a value error
ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.

How should I go about resolving that?

Comment: You need to provide your code with the error.

Comment: force the type to float32. I have update the answer